# How to make a function to calculate a quantity

Tags: c#

I'm setting a function to calculate the quantity in the sale bill and compare the quantity in my storage.

When i take quantity from an item the function compare the taken quantity with the total quantities in the grid.

Example:
Item x = 10, Item y = 5 and Item z = 6

When i take 5 from Item y then take 5 from item x it send objection that "the quantity is not available you have only 10"

```
    int Qte;
    string sumQte;
    //Calculate item quantity
    void sum_Quantity()
    {
        try
        {
            if (dgvSale.Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                sumQte = "0";
            }
            else 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvSale.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    sumQte = (from DataGridViewRow row in dgvSale.Rows
                              where row.Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString() 
                              != string.Empty &&
                              dgvSale.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == 
                              row.Cells[0].FormattedValue.
                              ToString()
                              select 
          Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
                    txtSumQte.Text = sumQte;
                    txtQte.Text = Convert.ToString(Qte);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
         return;
        }
     }
    if(Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text) > Qte)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Quantity is not available" + 
      Environment.NewLine + "You have : " 
                    + Qte.ToString(),"", 
      MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                txtQuantity.Clear();
                txtQuantity.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if(dgvSale.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text) + 
       Convert.ToInt32(sumQte.ToString()) > Qte)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This Quantity is not available" + 
            Environment.NewLine + "You have : "
                        + Qte.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
          MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    txtQuantity.Clear();
                    txtQuantity.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does this C# code use SQL or My-SQL, as it would be good to add some detail (in the code snippet or in the description) as to what you are using. Also please add a [sql] or [mysql] tag where appropriate.

Comment: @Boolean this code does not use any SQL. Even if it was it is irrelevant as the error is logical.

Comment: I get the data from SQL Server and i used  DataTable